# How to set the events in jQuery .on function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Looking to the bootstrap library I see that when using the .on function,
the event is written in this way:

```
  $(document).on('click.button.data-api', '[data-toggle^=button]', function (e) {
    // some code
  })
```

What is the purpose of writing the event as `click.button.data-api` instead of `click` ?
Is `click` enough?

Comment: `.button` and `.data-api` are namespaces in this case. I'm not sure what they are being used for internally by bootstrap, but yes `click` should be enough. Usually namespacing an event is done so that those events can be easily removed later without removing all click events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"button"` and `"data-api"` are the [event namespaces](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events), separated by `.` after the event name.

Sure it would work with just a `"click"`, but that will break unrelated code when bootstrap turns data API off with `.off("click")`. With namespaces, they can call `.off("click.data-api")` to remove only events that belong to the bootstrap data-api.

Comment: +1 thanks for your answer. And what about the namespace `button`. Can it be an element like `div` or a `class name` or what else?

Comment: @LorraineBernard `"button"` here doesn't refer to a button element, it's just an arbitrary string that namespaces the bootstrap button plugin. If you call `$(document).off( ".button" )`, then the bootstrap button widget would stop working for instance. Leaving the event name out here means all events that are in namespace `"button"`

Comment: So it means I can make something like `$(document).on('click.button.data-api.other-string' ...` and then `$(document).off('.other-string')` or `$(document).off('.button.data-api')` are all equivalent?

Comment: @LorraineBernard then that handler belongs to 3 different namespaces, and both `.off` calls qualify the handler to be removed. But they are not equivalent, `$(document).off('.other-string')` would just remove your custom handler, not bootstrap handlers belonging to button and data-api namespaces.